# How to check state of one thread from another in a thread safe way?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Background:

While debugging an application I came across this function

```
boolean IsThreadGood(Thread t)
{
    return t.IsAlive && t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running || t.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin;
}
```

I considered this to be a bug since the logical comparisons happening in the return statement are not atomic and therefore I thought the Thread t could change states while the expression was being executed.  To check this idea I changed the code to the following code so I could place breakpoints:

```
bool IsThreadGood(Thread t)
{
    if (t.IsAlive)
    {
        if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I placed breakpoint on the inner if statements and saw pretty quickly what I suspected.  When the code reached the first breakpoint Thread t had a ThreadState of WaitSleepJoin and when I stepped over the code to the next if statement Thread t had switched states and had a ThreadState of Running, thus failing  both tests and returning false from the method when it should return true.

My Question:

How can I make can I check the state of a thread from another thread in a thread safe way?

My ideas and what I've researched:

1. If I could make the statement atomic it would work.  I Googled some things like 'how to make a statement atomic in c#' and got a lot of results involving locks - not what I want because as I understand it locks don't make code atomic.
2. If I could suspend Thread t from the thread executing the method, then I could safely check its state.  What I found here are the obsolete functions Suspend and Resume.  Microsoft strongly recommends not using these.
3. Changing Thread t in some way to implement syncronization.  Not an option.  The code is reusable code that has been reused by different clients in different ways and Thread t is the client code.  Changing all of the clients won't be possible.

I'm not a multi-threading guru, so if any of my assumptions are incorrect or my understanding of multi-threading is incorrect, please feel free to point that out.

Comment: The current function returns true if the thread is "good" at all points where "goodness" is checked.  I'm not sure that it would be meaningful to find an atomic solution, if indeed there is one, because the thread could become not-good immediately after the function returns true.  Presumably this code is intended for a scenario where it is known that threads don't switch from good to not good with any frequency.

Comment: `var state = t.ThreadState; return state == ThreadState.Running || state == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin;`

Comment: @Eric J The method is used to remove threads that are not running from a queue. If the method leaves a thread in the queue that is not running that is ok because it will be removed the next time the method runs. But trying to remove a thread that is still running causes issues.

Comment: Then the current code should be fine.  It will have to pass all of the "goodness" checks in order to still be considered "good".  If it fails any one check, it is not running and will not return to a running state on its own.

Comment: Side note: Implementing reasonably working thread pool is hard. You may want to consider relying on tools provided by framework - i.e. Task with async/await may be suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m pretty sure that a thread which state is either `Running` or `WaitSleepJoin` cannot be not-alive. So you could just get the state (which is an atomic operation), and then check against those two values:

```
boolean IsThreadGood(Thread t)
{
    ThreadState state = t.ThreadState;
    return state == ThreadState.Running || state == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin;
}
```

Note that [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx#remarksToggle) explicitely points out that you should only use the thread state for debugging purposes, not for synchronization:

> Thread state is only of interest in debugging scenarios. Your code should never use thread state to synchronize the activities of threads.

Since you are interested in an atomic operation, I doubt that you want this for debugging purposes (otherwise you wouldn’t need to care about it being super precise). So you should probably think about solving your actual problem in a different way.

Comment: Note that the thread's real state could change right after assigning it to your local variable `state`.  The method call IsThreadGood is not atomic, in the sense of indicating the thread's true state at the point of the return statement.  However, that should not matter based on the OP's description of how the code is used in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**This can never work.** The thread could be at its last instruction and your check would miss the near and guaranteed exit. The thread must cooperate with you. You need to synchronize at a higher level. I can't suggest how because I don't know what the app does. Ask a new question with details and code.

Note, that `t.IsAlive && t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running || t.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin` misses braces around the `||` operator. Not that it matters because this code must be thrown away.

What is `state == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin` supposed to accomplish? This state can happen spuriously because many libraries might enter that state. This all seems bogus.

As a workaround you could implement a watchdog thread:

```
while (true)
 DetectExit();
 Sleep(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `Thread.Join(int millisecondsTimeout)` can be used to safely test whether thread has been completed. It returns true when the thread is no longer active.

```
 // 0 == don't wait.
 if (thread.Join(0))
 {
    // remove thread from the list
 }
```

For obvious reasons it should be called from another thread.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. He can already detect a thread that has ended.

Comment: He already reliably detects a thread exit as reliably as it possibly can be. The problem is that the thread can exit right after the check. The check only means something if an exit is detected.

Comment: @usr IsThreadGood() from OP can incorrectly return false when the state switches from WaitSleepJoin to Running.

Comment: I see. OK, let's wait for response from the OP what his problem actually is. Maybe this is what he's looking for. Good answer then.